# delay css animation opacity in styled-components

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styled-components

How to delay opacity to zero when certain condition is met in styled-component? Is it doable using css?

```
const Wrap = styled.div`
  background: #ddd;
  width: 100px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  opacity: ${props => (props.currentStep === props.steps ? 0 : 1)};
`;
```

demo

https://codesandbox.io/s/7k20zw5z10

What I want to achieve: the progress bar load till 100%, delay 1 second before the whole thing fade away.

Answer (score 1):

```
const Wrap = styled.div`
  background: #ddd;
  width: 100px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  opacity: ${props => (props.currentStep === props.steps ? 0 : 1)};
  transition: opacity 0.6s linear;
`;
```

you can add transition property to achieve the same

Comment: I want to let the progress load till the end then only fade away.

Comment: Can you give me an example

Comment: try to click the `add` button, you will notice the bar is gone before the animation of loading finished.