# delay css animation styled-component

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

How to delay opacity to zero when certain condition is met? The loader bar is controlled using js, is the delay doable using just css?

```
const Wrap = styled.div`
  background: #ddd;
  width: 100px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  opacity: ${props => (props.currentStep === props.steps ? 0 : 1)};
`;
```

demo (click on the add button)

https://codesandbox.io/s/7k20zw5z10

What I want to achieve: the progress bar load till 100%, delay 1 second before the whole thing got fade away.

Comment: Do you want that when the progress bar reaches 100% it will wait for a second until starting the fade away?

Comment: In this codesandbox there is actualy transition  with opacity set to 0.6s. Change it like you want

Comment: Possible duplicate of [delay css animation opacity in styled-components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55745325/delay-css-animation-opacity-in-styled-components)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [transition-delay](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition-delay):

```
const Wrap = styled.div`
  background: #ddd;
  width: 100px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  opacity: ${props => (props.currentStep === props.steps ? 0 : 1)};
  transition-delay: 2s;
`;
```

Demo:
https://codesandbox.io/s/mq51n0jmrp

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is with [CSS transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions):

```css
div {
  background: #ddd;
  width: 100px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 1s 2s;
}

div:hover {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

The transition will take 1s after a 2s delay.

Comment: shouldn't it be `transition: opacity 2s 1s;`? The second parameter is the delay

Comment: Isn't that what is explained below? It's just to make the demonstration a bit clearer

Comment: @Hanz You need to hover the div for 2 seconds before it works